# How to export async function?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, module, export

following is my code -

abc.js

```
 class abc {
   async foo1() {
     // do something
     return result;
   }
    async foo2() {
     // do something
     return result;
   }
   module.exports = abc
 }
```

another-file.js

```
const abc = requir(./abc);
abc.foo1();
// this results in error 
// TypeError : abc.foo1 is not a function
```

How should I do this?

Comment: `abc` is a class. You need an instance. This has nothing to do with async.

Answer (score 0):

Several points. By convention class names starts with capital letter. Your problem has nothing to do with async functions. You have 2 options to solve this problem. First option is to make your function static. Then you can use it directly without instance. Second option is just call it differently: instantiate class first to get instance, and then call your method on this instance. 
And also keep in mind, that await keyword can be used only inside other async function. And you need await keyword if you want to handle promise, returned by async function (it returns promise of `result`, not `result`)